# What is the difference between HTTPS and EAP-TLS?

Tags: tls

As far as I understand they do pretty much the same.

Comment: Different layers. One is for physical connections, one is for bits running through those connections. EAP is also just auth btw.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it lacks any research effort.

Comment: top hit for the search term "EAP-TLS" on Google: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Authentication_Protocol#EAP_Transport_Layer_Security_(EAP-TLS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no, they don't.

[HTTPS is HTTP over SSL/TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS). It is HTTP payload encapuslated in TLS transport.

[EAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Authentication_Protocol) is credential authentication protocol which is encapsulated in TLS.

They both serve very different tasks. What is common between them is TLS transport. But TLS doesn't care what is encapsulated inside, HTTP, EAP, SMTP, whatever else. Everything can be encapuslated into TLS. But HTTP and EAP are very different payloads and can work without TLS.